# Volume shader results different on cpu/gpu

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

I was trying to do some tutorials and experiments for Volume shader.
In a final render as well as in viewport I am getting totally different results with GPU and CPU. What is strange, when GPU (gtx 970) is used the Volume is very noisy and the quality is much lower (it looks very flat). This is first time i saw such difference in CPU vs GPU result. What is going on?

[GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCUqO.jpg)

[CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqqV6.jpg)

[BOTH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNQwX.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post images as links in your future questions - that makes it just a little more difficult for the people who are trying to help you. You can use the text editing tools of this website to insert images in a way that they are displayed without the need to follow any links.

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader for images so they appear inline. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Thank You for information and sorry for posting images as links (I got info that images are too big to use so I put links instead). So it seems that this volumetric rendering must be done in CPU in future. As far as I understand it is common problem.